# parse day time ranges with bash

Tags: bash, date, sed, awk, grep

I hope one of you bash, sed, awk experts out there can help me out.  I have this string:

```
 00:00:00:00:00:00%~%System1%~%s0:00-21:40%~%m3:10-17:10%~%t11:20-20:30%~%w05:10-9:30%~%t00:00-21:30%~%f12:00-0:00%~%s6:00-18:00
```

It is fields separated by "%~%".  The first two fields can be ignored.  The remaining fields have day time ranges.  This should clarify the format:

```
00:00:00:00:00:00 <--Mac
System1           <--Name
s00:00-21:40      <--Sunday 12 AM through 9:40 PM  
m03:10-17:10      <--Monday 3:10 AM through 5:10 PM
t11:20-20:30      <--Tuesday 11:20 AM through 8:30 PM
w05:10-9:30       <--Wednesday 5:10 AM through 9:30 AM
t00:00-21:30      <--Thursday 12 AM through 9:30 PM
f12:00-0:00       <--Friday 12 PM through 12:00 AM
s06:00-18:00      <--Saturday 6 AM through 6:00 PM
```

Now the trick...I need to determine if the current system datetime is within the ranges. :-(

So, if date returns this:

```
 Wed Sep 19 14:26:05 UTC 2012
```

Then it doesn't fall within the range specified for Wednesday. I basically need an if statement.  I need to execute one script if it is within the range and a different script if it is not.  How would I do that with bash, awk, and/or sed?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

I started going down this path:

```
arr=$(echo $line | tr "%~% " "\n")
for x in $arr
do
    #Now what?  Some kind of switch/case?
done
```

Comment: How do you tell the difference between "t12:34-13:45" (Tuesday) and "t12:34-13:45" (Thursday)? Same question for Saturday vs Sunday.

Comment: Yeah, good question...it is the order of the entries.  So, from that perspective, the letters for the days does nothing for us.  I know, kinda dumb.  Maybe I'll get it changed so that we just have the time ranges.  Doing that doesn't really help in solving the problem though.

Comment: In my for loop I could have an index that let's me know which one I'm on.  Then I could have a switch based on the index.

Comment: I don't have time to write on an answer, but I would highly recommend awk for this task rather than bash. Perhaps even a language with date libraries (eg perl, python, ruby).

Comment: A quick and dirty way, once you've figured out which entry you're trying to match, would be to just delete the ':' character in the range (changing "11:20-20:30" into "1120-2030") then do the same with the current date, and check to see if that number is between the two endpoints - the fact that there are numbers in the range that should never show up doesn't affect the fact that the numbers that do show up are still in the right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following script does what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function which returns true (0) on a time being in a range, false (1) otherwise
# call as: time_between $time $range
# where $range is of the format 'START-END'
time_between() {
    current_time=$1
    range=$2

    start_time=$(echo $range | cut -d'-' -f1);
    end_time=$(echo $range | cut -d'-' -f2);

    # Correct if ends at midnight
    if [[ $end_time -eq 0 ]]; then
        let end_time=2400
    fi

    # Test is time is within the window
    if [[ $current_time -ge $start_time && $current_time -le $end_time ]]
    then
         return 0;
    fi

    # Else the time is outside the window
    return 1;
}

# Set the line variable - you may want this to come from somewhere else in the end  
line="00:00:00:00:00:00%~%System1%~%s0:00-21:40%~%m3:10-17:10%~%t11:20-20:30%~%w05:10-9:30%~%t00:00-21:30%~%f12:00-0:00%~%s6:00-18:00"

i=0

# Extract the day and time (hours and minutes) from the `date` command
DATE=$(date)
day=$(echo $DATE | cut -d' ' -f1)

time=$(echo $DATE | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d: -f1-2 | tr -d ':')

# Marker for which token in the line to start the days from: token 3 is monday
dayno=2

# Set the dayno so we're pointing at the current day
case $day in
Mon)
    let dayno+=1
;;
Tue)
    let dayno+=2
;;
Wed)
    let dayno+=3
;;
Thu)
    let dayno+=4
;;
Fri)
    let dayno+=5
;;
Sat)
    let dayno+=6
;;
Sun)
    let dayno+=7
;;
esac

arr=$(echo $line | tr '%~%' '\n' | tr -d '[a-z]:')

for x in $arr
do
    let i+=1;
    #Now what?  Some kind of switch/case?
    if [[ $i -eq $dayno ]]; then
        if time_between $time $x; then
            echo "Were within the window!"
        else
            echo "We missed the window!"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using awk. I think the getline/coprocess feature is GNU Awk specific, so make sure you use that if you find this solution acceptable.

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN {
    RS = "%~%"
    "date +%w"   | getline dow
    "date +%H%M" | getline now
}

NR == 1      { mac = $0; next }
NR == 2      { sys = $0; next }

NR == 3+dow  {
    str = $0
    gsub(/[smtwf:]/, "", str)
    split(str, period, "-")
    next
 }

END {
    print "MAC:",  mac;
    print "System:", sys;
    print "Now:", now;
    print "Period:", period[1], period[2] ;

    if ((now >= period[1]) && (now <= period[2])) {
         # change this ...
         cmd = sprintf("echo matched - mac: %s system: %s", mac, sys)
         system(cmd)
    } else {
         # ... and this
         system("echo not matched")
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
$ date
Thu Sep 20 01:44:12 EEST 2012

$ echo "$data" | awk -f script.awk 
MAC: 00:00:00:00:00:00
System: System1
Now: 0145
Period: 0000 2130
matched - mac: 00:00:00:00:00:00 system: System1
```

I hope I've understood your problem correctly. Feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: I really like this answer but I'm using a trimmed version of Awk and it doesn't work for me.  That being said, I think this is a very clean way of doing it.

Comment: +1 `GNU awk` also has a function called `strftime` so I guess you could use that instead of the pipe to `getline`

Answer (score 1):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
echo "$string" | awk -f script.awk
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="%~%"
    day = strftime("%w") + 3
    time = strftime("%H%M")
}

{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (i == day) {
            gsub(/[a-z:]/,"")
            split($i, period, "-")
            if ((time >= period[1]) && (time <= period[2])) {
                print "yes, we're within today's range"
            }
            else {
                print "no, we're not within today's range"
            }
        }
    }
}
```